# How to bind Kibana to multiple host names / IPs

Tags: kibana

Is there a way to bind Kibana to more than one IP address using kibana's config file: `kibana.yml`? 
Right now, if I modify the line
`server.host: "127.0.0.1"`
to
`server.host: ["127.0.0.1","123.45.67.89"]`
which is valid YML, I get an error.
Is there any way to accomplish this from within Kibana or do I need to do it through a proxy/nginx?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try `0.0.0.0` if you want kibana to be available on real ip and localhost at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed!

Comment: For future readers trying to bind to several IPs, do you know if there's a way to list more than one anyway?

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is for all IPs of all interfaces.

Comment: @ipeacocks 0.0.0.0 is all IPv4 interfaces. To bind all IPv6 interfaces you need ::/0. You might also want both.

Comment: So there's still no way to specify multiple specific interfaces (such as localhost and 192.168.0.0/16)?

Comment: Funny thing that it requires the following format for ipv6:
server.host: "::"

Answer (score -6):

Install ngrok from https://ngrok.com/, then from your command line type:

```
ngrok http 5601
```

Ngrok will create a tunnel to the server and provide you with a url from which you can access your kibana UI.

If you need to acceess the ngrok and the 4040 port is closed on the server then do the same

```
ngrok http 4040
```